# inputConnection behaves differently in Activity and InputMethodService

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-input-method

I'm creating a custom keyboard using `LinearLayout`. On every key `TextView` click, `inputConnection` commits the text. It is working fine when `inputConnection.commitText` and `inputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor` is called from `Activity`. However, when it is called from `InputMethodService` then both of these functions don't work i.e., even `getTextBeforeCursor` returns `null` and `commitText` doesn't enter anything. Following is my `InputMethodService`

```
class MyInputMethodService : InputMethodService() {
    // hold the instance of Keyboard which is shared across Host App & Extension
    private lateinit var keyboardView: KeyboardView
    private lateinit var myContext:Context

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        Log.e("TKF", "onCreateInputView")
        myContext = ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_BasicM3App)

                           keyboardView =
            LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.fragment_keyboard, null) as KeyboardView
        keyboardView.setInputConnection(currentInputConnection, true)

        return keyboardView
    }
}
```

What can be possible reasons?